# c++ loop through registry recursively is slow

Tags: c++, python, registry

Have an annoying problem with my code, probably I am doing something wrong because my Python
implementation is much faster!

C++ implementation problems:

1. Iterating over "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" takes a lot of ram, I assume it's because c++ implementation uses lots of variables. ***Fixed***
2. It's also slow, much slower than python implantation of the code ***Fixed***
3. The code even slower when trying to iterate over HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ***Fixed***

New Questions:

1. Thanks to **Nam Nguyen** i understood what causing the leaks in my code, and directly effecting execution time, the code below is the fixed one. how come c++ implementation runs as fast as my python implementation?

C++ implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255

int RecurseOpenRegEx(HKEY hkey, string subKey = "",string search = "nothing", DWORD sum = 0)
{
   TCHAR csubKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
   DWORD nSubKeys = 0;
   DWORD pathLength = MAX_PATH;
   TCHAR storeKeyName[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
   DWORD keyLength;
   HKEY hKey = hkey; //somehow i need to reassign HKEY, otherwise it won't pass it with the function, this is bigger than me tough...

   const char * ccsearch = search.c_str();
   const char * ccsubKey;


   if (subKey != "")
   {
       ccsubKey = subKey.c_str();
       copy(subKey.begin(), subKey.end(),csubKey); //convert string to TCHAR
   }

   if (RegOpenKeyEx(hkey, ccsubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hkey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
   {
       if (RegQueryInfoKey(hkey, csubKey, &pathLength, NULL,&nSubKeys, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
       {
           sum += nSubKeys;
           for (DWORD subKeyIndex = 0; subKeyIndex < nSubKeys; subKeyIndex++)
           {
               keyLength = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
               if (RegEnumKeyEx(hkey, subKeyIndex, storeKeyName, &keyLength, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
               {
                   string sKeyName = storeKeyName; //Convert TCHAR to string explicitly


                   if (subKey != "")
                   {
                       sKeyName = subKey + "\\" + sKeyName;
                   }
                   sum += RecurseOpenRegEx(hKey, sKeyName);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   RegCloseKey(hkey); //Now closing the right key
   return sum;
}

int main()
{
   cout << "sum of all keys: " << RecurseOpenRegEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE);
   return 0;
}
```

Python implementation:

```
import winreg

def recurseRegistrySearch(key, keySearch = "",subkey = "", subkeypath = "", x = 0):
    key = winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey, 0)
    y = winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[0]
    x += y
    for items in range(x):
        try:
            subkey = winreg.EnumKey(key, items)
            if ((keySearch.lower() in subkey.lower()) and (keySearch != "")):
                print(subkeypath + "\\" + subkey)
            x += recurseRegistrySearch(key, keySearch, subkey, subkeypath = subkeypath + "\\" + subkey)
        except WindowsError:
            pass
    return x

print("sum of all keys: {0}".format(recurseRegistrySearch(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)))
```

Comment: implantation? I am not a native English speaker but I haven't ever heard about that in IT.

Comment: `subKey != ""` is just terrible.. Why not simply `!subKey.empty ()`?

Comment: Hello unwind, thanks for the edit :). @Vlad Lazarenko, thanks for the tip. though i don't think that i'll follow it. nevertheless thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is leak of resource in your code. You open `hkey` but you close `hKey` (note the difference in case of `k` and `K`).

On a side note, you store the opened registry key into `hkey` itself. And it happens that `hkey` is the passed in parameter, shared among all calls to `RecurseOpenRegEx`. That is why "somehow i need to reassign HKEY".

Basically, what I can advise you now is immediately clean up your code. Bugs like these are hard to spot when your code is a too difficult to read. Once done, I believe you will find it easier to debug/trace.

Comment: About the leak, I'll check it and tell you my findings, thanks for the info! Can you please clarify: "...you store the opened registry key into hkey itself."

Comment: The fourth parameter to ``RegOpenKeyEx(hkey, ccsubKey, 0, KEY_READ, &hkey)`` is a pointer to a HKEY to receive the opened key. Normally, it should be different than the first parameter.

Comment: I meant the fifth parameter, not fourth.

Comment: thanks mate, it was the leak you talked about that made things slower. fixed it and now the c++ implementation runs as fast as my python implementation. i'm sure there is more to it tough. trying to understand what else need to be done to make the code run faster... i have edited the code i've posted and my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's your heavy use of string variables ,which involves a lot of dynamic memory allocations.

Try accepting parameters as LPCTSTR .assign string variables inside the function with those LPCTSTRs and pass parameters with str.c_str().

Comment: Hey there, implemented what you've suggested and it didn't made any real time saving changes... I will add that i am checking the code on my machine (windows 7 x64 ultimate), and when i run through "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT" i find there 1,127,000 keys... All in all i still can't figure how python is on the same level of performance regarding this kind of task.